# Report cuts off in web application only

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is not Shown properly. It cuts off in my Web Application (.net MVC Aspx). However the same .rpt works properly in the desktop application. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you configured the report to use No Printer in *File -> Page Setup*?

Comment: @4444 yes i had chosen but main issue is SAp Framing is not fully overlay to Browser window you can see it in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal report width has a minimum of value only. If your report need to have a wide width then use landscape set up for your report display view.

Also use suppressed option on each specific report fields.

Comment: hello @reds its all set but main issue is Framing done By SAP window is not Fill browser..If it done than report shows properly.

Comment: @Mahendra its not issue of page its issue of outer framing of crystal report i mean toolbar and etc.